# JavaScript balloon comic text recognition

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing, ocr, image-recognition

As you can see from the image I found online, I would like to be able to take the texts that are inside the comic balloon.

Can you give me some advice on what I could use?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This javascript framwork may help you check it out
[Tesseract.js](https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com)